# Visual Studio auto updates references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget-package

I'm working on a .NET application with multiple projects. Whenever I install a NuGet package reference to a specific project, Visual Studio auto adds references to `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` and `Newtonsoft.Json` into other project files in the background. How I can stop this? I've been struggling to find if there is a specific setting or why this is happening in the first place as I do not want these references and I've to manually discard changes.

Comment: it's not that the specific package has those as dependencies?

Comment: This should not happen normally. Are you still using the old `packages.config` way of declaring your references?

Comment: No, the packages have no dependencies as such. This behaviour is same irrespective of the package I install. 
@PMF: Yes, it's a legacy application and uses packages.config.

Comment: @dark_cypher Then I would upgrade to packagereferences. packages.config did have such problems from the beginning, and I doubt they'll fix anything about that.